# Visual studio 2019 compile and build

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Im learning c++, just began and want to make sure I got it right, in visual studio; pressing compile  and after that build is that the same thing as pressing **Local Window Debugger** with the Release option?

Comment: Not really, compile compiles one file, build builds the program, debugger starts the debugger. Each of these actions can cause the other actions to happen (but not necessarily).

Comment: ok, at least they create the same files but that might be because I only have got one file in my test project? ... So I try again :)  compile first compiles the cpp file down to obj file. Then build builds it down to exe file. While Local Window Debugger also includes the linker which basically kind of finds the correct files that is included in my code ...?

Comment: That's more or less right, but VS includes an option the automatically build an out of date project before lauching the debugger, this option is on by default. But if you turned it off then Local Windows Debugger would not invoke the linker or compiler.

Comment: Thanks! Two more questions: 1) Local Window Debugger would then be the same as running `cl myApplication.cpp` in the terminal? 2) running build in Visual studio is basically to run the linker?

Comment: Not really. The debugger is a tool for debugging your programs, its well worth learning how to use, but it's not the same as `cl myApplication.cpp` which is how you would run the compiler (and linker?, not sure about that) from the terminal. And build in visual studio builds your program which would normally involve running the compiler and the linker (although other tools could be involved as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, compiling and building is basically the same as creating files when using Local Windows Debugger in Release mode. But the Local Windows Debugger will start the application and open the debugger, so it will perform some other operations.

Second, cl [filename] and then run in the terminal is very different from the local window debugger. The local window debugger will perform additional optimization according to the settings and provide us with the corresponding information according to the specific command line parameters, while the cl command needs to provide more option commands at build time, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-command-line-syntax?view=vs-2019.

Finally, running the build in Visual Studio first compiles the source code into an object file, and then links the external file to form an executable file. It also includes our optimization and control of the generated program. We can change it by adding command line parameters or in the Visual Studio settings.